# enabling phone call from number present in listview

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-widget

As i am new to android i need help from the member of stackoverflow.
In my android project, i have a string array of company name with there contact number listed in same string array - item.

my list view is working fine with the filter feature in list view.
i just want the user can directly initiate a phone call on that number from my listview.

```
<item >Citizen Company - 731429278838 </item>
```

i want user can directly dial the given phone number.

here is my code please have a look and notify me for my mistake.

```
public class Taximain extends Activity {
// List view
private ListView lv;
// Listview Adapter
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
// Search EditText
EditText inputSearch;
// ArrayList for Listview
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.taxi_main);
    // Listview Data
    String products[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Taxi);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
    // Adding items to listview
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.taxi_listitem, R.id.product_name, products);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);   
    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            Taximain.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of you all you have to make array of company and his number.

Make custom listview with company and number.

Now you can used `setOnItemClickListener` and make a call.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id){
            Intent callintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:" + phone_arr[position]));
            startActivity(callintent);                    
        }
 });
```

You can used [this](http://android-helper.blogspot.in/2011/04/android-listview-onclick-ample.html) listview and make some modification.

**update:**

Strint [] **phone_arr**={1234567890,9999999999,....}

always same size of your **products**.

Answer (score 1):

The special [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) you're looking for is [ACTION_DIAL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DIAL).

I assume you're able to get the phone number quite easily, so here's how you would want to use it:

```
String tel = // Get phone number;

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);                          
intent.setData(Uri.parse(String.format("tel:%s", tel)));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

By using intent "ACTION_CALL" will enable a phonecall from listview item's click.

```
String callString="tel:"+phone_arr[position];
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(callString));  
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: @madhuri- MAM,
please have a re look at my code and suggest me please.